# Understanding capacitive current

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis

In the context of understanding neurons as parallel circuits (see for instance [here  page 12](https://www.math.fsu.edu/~bertram/lectures/HH_model.pdf)), the following formulas are used:

C = \$ \frac{Q}{V} \iff \$

C * V = Q \$\iff \$

C\$\frac{dV}{dt}\$ = \$\frac{dQ}{dt} \iff \$

C*\$\frac{dV}{dt}\$ = \$I_{C}  \$

With C = capacitance; V = Voltage; Q = Charge; \$I_{C}\$ = Capacitive current

**My questions:**

(1) As far as I know, current is defined by \$ I = \frac{Q}{t} \$ as charge (Coulomb) over time (seconds). Here, however, the *change* of charge over time is equated with current. How is this justified?

(2) Both charge and voltage are differentiated, capacitance remains constant, however. Why is that?

(3) What is the capacitive current in this context? Is this current flowing through the circuit, or rather movement of particles on the capacitor's plate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) I'd say the notation \$I={Q \over t}\$ is confusing. As [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_current) states it:

> An **electric current** is the rate of flow of electric charge past a point or region.

Right there we should key on the phrase *rate* of flow. And it's pretty intuitive too -- when we think about current, it is simply moving charge from one place to another, so all that matters is the *change* in the amount of charge, not the absolute amount. So I'd say it would be more accurate to write \$I={\Delta Q \over \Delta  t}\$, but in practice people don't do this. At any rate, in this context, \$I={dQ \over dt}\$ should hopefully make perfect sense.

(2) Simply because the capacitor value is constant. If you replaced the constant \$C\$ with a number (say, 2.5), then seeing \$2.5 * V = Q\$ differentiated into \$2.5 {dV \over dt} = {dQ \over dt}\$ would make perfect sense. So just remember that \$C\$ is a constant, not a time-varying quantity.

(3) It is the current flowing through the capacitor, in one terminal and out the other. (Sorry for the... unreasonable... size of the schematic image...)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiYWWF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: (1) Say, however, we have a constant current, e.g. 3 Amps = 3 Coloumbs/second. Would then dQ/dt not equal zero, as per definition the current's "strength" is not changing? (2) But the capacitance is a function of Voltage (and charge), so how comes changing the voltage is not changing it? (3) How can the current flow "through" the capacitor when its inside is an insulator? Thx

Comment: (1) dQ/dt *is* 3 Amps. If the current's "strength" were changing, then that would be dI/dt (font doesn't do well here -- that is dee-eye-dee-tee there). To put it a different way, 3 amps means that every second 3 Coloumbs of charge are moving from point A to point B.  (2) Nope, capacitance is not a *function* of voltage or charge. It is a *relationship between them* but changing the voltage (or the charge) does not change capacitance, ...

Comment: (3) Current can flow through the capacitor, but not continuously. Imagine a pipe filled with water, and in the middle of a pipe is a rubber diaphragm which completely seals off one end of the pipe from the other. Now force some water into one side of the pipe. The diaphragm will stretch, and water will get pushed out the other side of the pipe. Some water flowed in and an equal amount came out the other end, so in the simplest sense water flowed "through". But you couldn't keep this up continuously, the diaphragm would exert too much reverse force or break. It's very similar with a capacitor.

Comment: Thank you:-)....

Comment: Strictly, current does not flow *through* a capacitor. Nothing goes through the dielectric, apart from a small leakage current. Current charges/discharges the plates.

Comment: @Chu So I_C is indeed movement of the particles on the plates, as the result of the current flowing through the entire circuit? Or is I_C here the leakage current (= capacitive current)?

Comment: Leakage current is tiny and usually ignored. Current flows to charge the plates only. If the source is direct voltage then current flows to deposit charge on the plates, and when the capacitor is fully charged, current ceases. If the source is an alternating voltage, current flows to and fro, charging the plates alternately positive then negative during each cycle.

Comment: got it, thx....